# Problems with pliman library interactive functions

Tags: r, plot

I'm currently using pliman for measuring some disease area of leaves. theres this function `measure_disease_iter()` that let you sample directly from the image the color palette for background healthy tissue and disease. The problem is that when i click the image my click is displaced from its original position as it the image was displaced or something.

I already tried resize the images without solution, even using another image formats, but nothing change the result. Any idea? Thanks